# In Backbone views, which is better: this.$el.find('.selector') or this.$('.selector')?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

Both of these work, and FF console shows that they are selecting the same element, but is there any advantage of using one over the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar):

> **$ (jQuery)** `view.$(selector)`
>
> [...] It's equivalent to running: `view.$el.find(selector)`

So `this.$(selector)` is just short hand for `this.$el.find('.selector')`. Use whichever one you prefer, there's no functional difference between them.